# How should I structure my Javascript code in files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On an average I have 30-50 lines of javascript specific to the page (it is not common). How should I structure my Javascript code so that it gets downloaded in an optimal manner on the client.

If I put that in a common Javascript file then the initial page download will take time because it will even download Javascript code that is not for that page.

If I put it embedded within the page itself then disadvantage is that it is never cached.

How should I structure it in optimal manner? I have round about 30-50 pages in my application.

Comment: similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219285/how-do-you-manage-your-javascript-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When developing, use a logic folder structure so you can put all files in a folder and you can find them easier. When in production, concat and minify your code/files and use one reference to that minified file.

If you want to seperate even in production, think of a way to concat files as much as possible and minify that files. To load files when needed, you can think of a library as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: @aszz: So you mean a single file that downloads the script for all of the pages in a single go?

Comment: @TimTom: At least as much as possible. If putting all your code in one file is to much overhead, you can separate the code somewhat use RequireJS to load the files at the moment they are needed. But, mostly, one minified file is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same directory/file structure under js as I have for the html (php) files, so when I'm on any url (/example1/example2) I include /js/example1/example2.js